# Can the compiler assume that malloc will never return NULL?

Tags: c, memory, null, malloc

In [this video](https://youtu.be/w3_e9vZj7D8?t=3843) it is mentioned that the compiler can assume that `malloc` never returns `NULL` and is allowed to optimize accordingly. I have never heard of this and couldn't find any reference to it in the C-Standard. Can anyone tell me if this is true and if so, where this behaviour is specified?

The code shown in the video at this point is:

```
if((a = malloc(1024)) == NULL)
    printf("We are out of memory!\n");
else
    free(a);
```

Comment: It's not true, at least not in the general sense. Maybe there are specific environments where malloc is guaranteed to succeed, but I'm not familiar with them.

Comment: https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1548.pdf (C11 standard) <- "The malloc function returns either a **null pointer** or a pointer to the allocated space."

Comment: Lets take a simpler example: `int a = 10; if (a == 10) { a = 5; }`. It's rather easy to see that this could be transformed into `int a = 5;`. This is basically what that part of the video is about: The compiler can simply remove (or not include) parts of the code if it doesn't matter for the program. This is permissible because of the [*as if* rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/as_if). At least that's what I *hope* the author of the video is meaning. Because there's no "assumption" that memory can always be allocated.

Comment: That's not to say that `malloc` might ever return a non-null pointer, because on some operating systems it almost never does. Take for example Linux, which uses *overcommit* of memory allocations, where allocations almost never fails even if the virtual memory is overcommited. This is because few applications uses all the pages of their allocated memory, or does use them in a way that pages can be reused for other processes, and so the OS can juggle pages between processes to satisfy most use-cases.

Comment: @Mat, I don't see why. If the value of a pointer to an allocated object is not observable outside then the `malloc()` could be optimized out by assuming it always succeeds.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, I think that in practice for user-space programs running on modern OS it can be always assumed that allocation smaller than a memory page always succeeds. Failing `malloc()` will simply not return.

Comment: Four reasons to check what the malloc function returned - https://pvs-studio.com/en/blog/posts/cpp/0938/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The speaker does not mean the compiler can assume `malloc` never returns a null pointer. They mean in the specific case shown, the compiler can see what the code does and that it can be implemented without calling `malloc` at all and, equivalently, it can be optimized as if `malloc` never returns null in that specific situation.

The C standard allows a compiler to implement code in any way that produces the specified *observable behavior*, which is, from C 2018 5.1.2.3 6:

> - Accesses to volatile objects are evaluated strictly according to the rules of the abstract machine.
> - At program termination, all data written into files shall be identical to the result that execution of the program according to the abstract semantics would have produced.
> - The input and output dynamics of interactive devices shall take place as specified in 7.21.3. The intent of these requirements is that unbuffered or line-buffered output appear as soon as possible, to ensure that prompting messages actually appear prior to a program waiting for input.

Note that `malloc` is not part of the observable behavior. It is inside the C implementation, which means the compiler is allowed to optimize how it behaves. Even if there is a separate library that provides `malloc`, the compiler is allowed to treat that as just an assist to C implementation and optimize uses of `malloc` in the program.

Comment: The speaker actually says explicitly (around 1:04:19) that the compiler can assume the memory is allocatble and therefore malloc will not return NULL.  Which seems wrong to me.

Comment: @wohlstad: That statement is made in the context of the displayed code, and it is an optimization allowed by the C standard in that context.

Comment: As far as I saw the speaker did not show any code surrounding the malloc handling to give context, and did not mention it.

Comment: @wohlstad: The code shown in the video at that point is `if((a = malloc(1024)) == NULL) printf("We are out of memory!\n"); else free(a);`. The fact that the physical computer might be out of memory at that point is irrelevant; the C standard specifies C inside an abstract machine. Environmental limits are allowed by the C standard but are not required. It is permissible to design a compiler for an abstract machine that conceptually has memory available at that point in the code, even if the physical implementation does not. Therefore, the compiler may optimize as if the `malloc` works.

Comment: @SupportUkraine: As long as the `malloc` works, which may be true inside the abstract machine (see above comment), the `printf` is call is never executed, so it may be optimized away.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I think I understand. You mean that this _can_ be the behavior in a specific theoretical compiler (i.e. this compiler will not violate the C standard), not that you expect _"normal"_ / common compilers to do it, right ?

Comment: The `malloc()` call may return `NULL` well outside the control of the compiler, or the library implementation, **unless** that libary implementation *itself* has optimized the system call out of its `malloc()` *and has told the compiler that it did*. The mechanics how that would be possible within the scope of the standard escape me at the moment. Anyway, it cannot be a valid optimization *in the general case*, because the general case is that `malloc()` may well return `NULL`.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the discussion. This is very helpful and interesting!

Comment: @wohlstad: Yes.

Comment: @SupportUkraine: The compiler is simply never required to call the external `malloc` routine. What the C standard requires of a C implementation is that it provide the memory management functions specified in C 2018 7.22.3 **to the program**. If the compiler figures “Hey, I can give you that memory you want without calling the external `malloc`”, that is a valid optimization. Imagine the program is executing inside an abstract machine, which is how the C standard specifies it. Inside that abstract machine, the program calls `malloc`, gets a pointer to 1024 bytes,…

Comment: … sees the pointer is not null (because this abstract machine always has memory available at this point in the source code), and calls `free`. So, it is entirely allowed by the C standard for the program to behave this way. Now, how would you implement this behavior of the abstract machine? You do not have to call the external `malloc` in the physical machine to do it. We know what the behavior of the program is: This particular code has no observable side effects. So we can implement it by doing nothing, including not calling the external `malloc`.

Comment: @SupportUkraine: [Clang makes this optimization.](https://godbolt.org/z/zTrPdbWrj)

Comment: Doesn't mean that's correct behavior *in the general case*.

Comment: So to get this clear. I could be using my own implementation of the library functions, including `malloc()`. I could, conceivably, implement `void * malloc( size_t size ) { return NULL; }`, which would be within the letter of the standard. And you say that the compiler would be at liberty to *ignore* that and optimize that `printf()` away. I find that... bold.

Comment: @DevSolar: Re “correct behavior *in the general case*”: Nobody is asserting `malloc` can be optimized away in “the general case.” Re “the compiler would be at liberty to *ignore* that”: It is quite simple, the external library is not the C implementation. It is an assist to the C implementation The compiler, the library, the hardware, and the operating system all together form the C implementation. The compiler may use them as it chooses, as long as it implements the abstract semantics specified by the C standard…

Comment: … For example, the I/O and conversion routines are not required to convert floating-point numbers with fully correct rounding, but a C compiler could provide its own correctly rounded conversions, ignoring the external routines, and the result would still be a C implementation that conforms to the C standard. Or, from another perspective, if link to a completely different conforming implementation of the standard C library rather than the system default, that would still be a conforming C implementation, because there is no obligation to use any particular implementation…

Comment: … It does not matter whether you find it bold or not; the responsibility of the C implementation is to implement the semantics defined by the abstract machine, not to mechanically issue calls to the external library. If you think optimizing away a call to `malloc` is not allowed by the C standard, then do not tell us you find it bold, tell us which paragraph of the standard disallows it.

Comment: Let's just agree to disagree. I find this interpretation of the standard to be **violently** faulty.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251912/discussion-between-devsolar-and-eric-postpischil).

Comment: @DevSolar: Re “Let's just agree to disagree”: No, this is determined by the C standard. The standard requires a program’s observable behavior to be as if it were executing on an abstract machine, and it does not require the `malloc` in the abstract machine to be implemented by calling any particular `malloc` implementation. The observable behavior is accesses to volatile objects, data written into files by program termination, and the input and output dynamics of interactive devices.